# Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger' : "AspNetCore.Serilog.RequestLoggingMiddleware"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, serilog

I am new to programming, I am trying to implement a logging solution for .net core project.

I want to collect Default and Microsoft category logs.

APPSETTING.JSON

```
      {
          "Serilog": {
              "MinimumLevel": {
                  "Default": "Information",
                  "System": "Warning",
                  "Microsoft": "Information"
              },
              "File": {
                  "location": "logs/timeapi.log"
              }
          },
          "EnableSwagger": true
      }
```

PROGRAM.CS

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

STARTUP.CS

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
            options.RequestProjection =
            r => new { r.IsHttps, QueryString = r.QueryString.Value });
        app.UseMvc();
```

```
https://github.com/mthamil/AspNetCore.Serilog.RequestLoggingMiddleware
```

The error I am getting is :

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'AspNetCore.Serilog.RequestLoggingMiddleware.SerilogRequestMiddleware'.
```

Comment: are you missing a `.UseSerilog` ?

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thanks, it didnt fixed after adding that :(

Comment: Sorry, not paying attention - in general, the UseSerilog will register a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` - the chances are that wouyld have worked without adding a UseSerilog. Unfortunately I have not played with it much so can't offer a link to a getting started with Serilog on aspnetcore article :(

Comment: @RubenBartelink the twist here is that it's not the _Serilog.AspNetCore_ `UseSerilogRequestLogging()` but another impl I hadn't previously seen

Answer (score 12):

The middleware you're using appears to need Serilog's `ILogger` added in the app's [`Startup.ConfigureServices()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2); e.g.:

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(Log.Logger);
    }
```

(This example assumes you're configuring Serilog's `Log.Logger` static property.)

There's a more complete example of setting up request logging with Serilog in the readme for the [*Serilog.AspNetCore* package](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore), though its implementation of `UseSerilogRequestLogging()` is quite different.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using .net core 3.1 + only use it in program.cs like this and remove every thing about Serilog from startup.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
    .WriteTo.Console())
    ......;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a bug on the middleware itself : https://github.com/mthamil/AspNetCore.Serilog.RequestLoggingMiddleware/issues/3